# Multiple autolayout animations issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uiviewanimation

So I have a animation that moves a view from left to right and bounce once and after .2 seconds I start the same animation for a second view. The problem is the layoutIfNeeded in the first animation affects the second one and I'm not getting the 0.2 seconds delay. Any way around this?
(I think I can go around it by adding each row in their own superview and running layoutIfNeeded on that but I'd like to keep the number of views to a minimum)
So here's my code:

```
[self removeConstraint:_thirdRowConstraint];
    _thirdRowConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:row3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self addConstraint:_thirdRowConstraint];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay: 0 options: 0 animations:^{
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self removeConstraint:_thirdRowConstraint];
    _thirdRowConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:row3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:20];
    [self addConstraint:_thirdRowConstraint];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeConstraint:_thirdRowConstraint];
        _thirdRowConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:row3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
        [self addConstraint:_thirdRowConstraint];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }];
}];

[self removeConstraint:_forthRowConstraint];
    _forthRowConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:row4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self addConstraint:_forthRowConstraint];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay: 0.2 options: 0 animations:^{
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self removeConstraint:_forthRowConstraint];
    _forthRowConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:row4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:20];
    [self addConstraint:_forthRowConstraint];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeConstraint:_forthRowConstraint];
        _forthRowConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:row4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
        [self addConstraint:_forthRowConstraint];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }];
}];
```